# Android Webview alongside other buttons

Tags: android, webview

When adding webview to an activity it seems to take over the whole activity. What I want is a small webview along side some buttons, but when I change size of webview it makes little difference.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Tab3Activity extends Activity
{

    private WebView mWebview ;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab3);


        mWebview = new WebView(this);

        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // enable javascript

        final Activity activity = this;

        mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
                Toast.makeText(activity, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
        });
        mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        mWebview.clearCache(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android WebView");
        mWebview.loadUrl(MainActivity.MapLocation);
        setContentView(mWebview);

    }
}
```

Comment: where you want to place the buttons left, right, top or bottom?

Comment: Really just don't want to webview to take over the activity, was looking for some kind of code to make it smaller.

Comment: Where are your buttons?

Comment: @PrerakSola have not added them as yet.

Comment: try something with frame layout it can consist your full webview and buttons above it

Comment: You have to assign your desired height and width in this case and place where ever you want. And if you want buttons in there for example at the bottom of your `WebView` then set the `WebView` above those buttons adn buttons to bottom.

Comment: Thanks but have tried to change width and height but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this and maintain the **layout_weight** as per your requirement.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.demo.MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

    </WebView>

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_x="154dp"
        android:layout_y="431dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

May this helps you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.demo.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" >

    </WebView>

    <Button
        android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_x="154dp"
        android:layout_y="431dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Still full screen webview

Comment: Actually at which side u need a button?

Comment: Any really. Just want webview that does not consume the full page. I actually had the code for this a while ago, but seem to have misplaced it.

Comment: Sure. What do you mean.

Comment: just try the below code and now I hope that you are finding the solution like this only.